# Hard Probability Inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

I am new in this forum and I am happy to find it, because it seems a very precious place for asking questions.
My question is  about some probability inequality. I formulate this as following.
Let $(X_k)_{1\leq k \leq K}$, with $K$ a nonzero integer, be a discrete-random variables live in   $\{2, ..., n\}$ where $n \geq 2$ . Then, if  $(n_k)_{0\leq k \leq K}$, with $n_0 =1$, is a sequence of integers in  $\{1, ..., n\}$, one can prove that
$$ \mathbb{P}\big( \exists k\in \{1, ...., K\};\, X_k \leq n_{k-1}\big) \leq \sum_{k=1}^K 2^{k-1}\mathbb{P}\big(\max\{ 1\leq \ell \leq K; X_\ell \leq n_{\ell-1}\} = k\big).
$$

Thank you very much for your sugggestions,

Emera

Answer (score 1):

Do I overlook something? Can't we just argue that $\def\P{\mathbb P}$
$$ \P(\exists k; X_k \le n_{k-1}) = \sum_{k=1}^K \P(\max_{X_\ell \le n_{\ell -1}} \ell = k) $$
as if there is a $k$, there is exactly one maximal such. Now as $1 \le 2^{k-1}$ for $1 \le k \le K$ we are done.

Comment: Thank you Martini for your suggestion. Yes, your equality is true, here the proof


\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{P}\bigg( \exists k\in \{1, ...., K\}:\, X_k \leq n_{k-1}\bigg)
&=&\mathbb{P}\bigg( \sqcup_{k=1}^K \max_{ 1\leq \ell \leq K} \{X_\ell \leq n_{\ell-1}\} = k\bigg) \textrm{Disjoint union}\\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^K \mathbb{P}\bigg(\max_{ 1\leq \ell \leq K} \{X_\ell \leq n_{\ell-1}\} = k\bigg)
\end{eqnarray*}.

But I think that the coefficient $2^{k-1}$ does not become from the inequality of $1\leq 2^{k-1}$. How much is hard to point out this coefficnet !